# NSDate dateFromString returns nil on Device Language Change

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have written a simple function to return the NSDate from an NSString. But it is always returning nil.

#### The scenario is:

1. The device language is English, the function works fine.
2. The device language is Arabic, the functions returns nil.

The NSString value is "03:43 PM". However if the date is formatted in arabic i.e "٠٩:٥٦ ص". It returns a correct date. Any idea?

**Code:**

```
- (NSDate*) GetTime:(NSString*) txt
{
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    
    return [df dateFromString:txt];
}
```

Comment: That code should work.

Comment: Surprisingly it is not. @Droppy

Comment: Does the NSString value change at all between English and Arabic? Date formatters will return nil for a date if it can't parse the string. Since you are setting your format to `@"hh:mm a"`, if you pass it any string that doesn't exactly match that format, it will return nil.

Comment: may be the reason will occur check one your `txt` also pass the arabhic string bz I also face the same issue on locaization

Comment: @RPK no both ways I am passing the date in English.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes indeed, if my device's language is Arabic and I pass the string as arabic format, it returns a correct date. What shall I do, if all the dates strings I have in English, I cannot translate them to arabic.

Comment: You can explicitly set the locale of the date formatter to the US. That way it doesn't use the devices current locale.

Comment: @RPK has the correct solution.

Comment: @RPK Yes Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going by the comments above, set the locale as follows

```
- (NSDate*) GetTime:(NSString*) txt
{
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    return [df dateFromString:txt];
}
```

This will ensure that no matter the devices locale, if you are passing it an english string for the time in the required format, it will properly create an `NSDate`.

Comment: Yes, I was having the same Problem for date formatter. Once I set `[df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];` , then it worked.

Comment: Awesome simple answer.